# Python - link database query to python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I have a spreadsheet with seven thousand rows of user ids. I need to query a database table and return results matching the ids in the spreadsheet.

My current approach is to read the entire database table into a pandas data frame and then merge with another data frame created from the spreadsheet. I'd prefer not to read the entire table into memory due to it's size. Is there anyway to do this without reading in the entire table? In Access or SAS, I could write a query that links the locally created table (i.e. created from spreadsheet) with the database table.

Current code that reads entire table into memory

```
# read spreadsheet
external_file = pd.read_excel("userlist.xlsx")

# query
qry = "select id,term_code,group_code from employee_table"

# read table from Oracle database
oracle_data = pd.read_sql(qry,connection)

# merge spreadsheet with oracle data
df = pd.merge(external_file,oracle_data,on=['id','term_code'])
```

I realize the following isn't possible but I would like to be able to query the database like this where "external_file" is a data frame created from my spreadsheet (or at least find an equivalent solution):

```
query = """
select a.id,
a.term_code,
a.group_code
from employee_table a
inner join external_file b on a.id = b.id and a.term_code=b.term_code
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use a xlwing (https://www.xlwings.org) to create a function that reads the id columns and create the query you want